# Laravel blog rating 2 migrations

Tags: laravel, foreach

i made a blog in laravel and  now created a new migration for a rating system. i call it with

```
@foreach($blogs as $key => $blog)
    $blog->title....
    @foreach($ratings as $key => $rating)
        @if( $rating->blog_id == $blog->id)
        <br> rating found!
        <br> {{ $rating->rating_total }}
        <br> {{ $rating->rating_amount }}
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

it works but it doesnt seem right to run a for loop on every blog post in order to get the rating.

how can i solve this better?

thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO ... did you setup a relationship from Blog to Rating? (assuming you are using Eloquent)

Comment: thanks for the welcome. yes i can call ```$rating = Blog::find(1)->rating;``` in controller but dont know how to get it for every blog id in blade

Comment: Are you asking about [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)? `$blogs = Blog::with('rating')->get();` and then `foreach ($blogs ...) { // now you have $blog->title, $blog->rating->rating_total;...` etc?

Comment: (In fact you don't even *need* to eager load for that to work - if you have relationshps set up, you can do `$blog->rating->rating_total` any time.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use one that show this. Like this: `<input id="input-1" name="input-1" class="rating rating-loading" data-min="0" data-max="5" data-step="0.1" value="{{ $post->averageRating }}" data-size="xs" disabled="">`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the relationship setup from Blog to Rating you can eager load the 'rating' relationship for each Blog post:

```
$blogs = Blog::with('rating')->...->get();
```

Then in Blade when you are looping your `$blogs` you will have access to it's rating:

```
@foreach($blogs as $blog)
    {{ $blog->title }}
    @if($blog->rating)
        {{ $blog->rating->rating_total }}
        {{ $blog->rating->rating_amount }}
    @endif
@endforeach
```